# Visual Studio 2015 compiling against a project reference instead of the defined dll reference

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, project-reference

I have a Visual Studio 2015 solution with two projects: `<foo>` and `<bar>`. `<bar>` compiles to `<bar.dll>`. `<foo>` has a reference to `<bar.dll>` and NOT to the `<bar>` project. When I try to compile `<foo>`, it appears to be looking at the  project instead of the existing `<bar.dll>`.

Another developer has added a class to `<bar>`, compiled it, and provided an updated dll to me for testing. I have the updated dll, but my local copy of the source code for `<bar>` doesn't have their new code. Since my `<foo>` project has a reference to `<bar.dll>`, I'm expecting it to see what's in the dll and not care about what's in my `<bar>` project. However, my code in `<foo>` that references their new class causes an error (class not found).

If I open a new instance of Visual Studio and only load the `<foo>` project, it compiles just fine. No changes to references or anything.

Comment: It makes very little sense to have a project whose output you want to use, but also whose output you DON'T want to use. Maybe the Visual Studio is as confused as me. If removing the project works for you, I'd suggest to just go with it.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you're using source control to share the changes that each other make! This would be the better solution, the other developer wouldn't need to manually send a copy of the dll and you wouldn't be fighting Visual Studio.

Comment: We're using SourceGear Vault and the other person's code hasn't been checked in yet. I'm absolutely love to move us to git, but that's not a small feat. And yes, maybe VS is confused, but I don't see why it should be. I'm explicitly telling VS to use the DLL. I don't understand why it even cares about my other project. Easy work-around? Yes. Root cause? Hmm...